# How can I reduce my array in Swift in the given format? Am not able to get the logic

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct, reduce

I have a struct and an Array as follows

```
struct MyStruct : Codable {
   var name:String
   var slot:String
   var id: Int
}

struct NewStruct : Codable {
   var name:String
   var slot:[String]
   var id: Int
}

let data1 = MyStruct(name: "Ankit", slot: "1", id: 11)
let data2 = MyStruct(name: "Deric", slot: "1", id: 12)
let data3 = MyStruct(name: "Ankit", slot: "2", id: 11)
let data4 = MyStruct(name: "Deric", slot: "2", id: 12)
let data5 = MyStruct(name: "RandomName1", slot: "1", id: 13)
let data6 = MyStruct(name: "RandomName2", slot: "1", id: 14)
let data7 = MyStruct(name: "Ankit", slot: "3", id: 11)

var arrayOfData = [data,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6,data7]
```

am expecting that repeated name or say id should be merged and slot should have an array of the respective name or id, for reference
am expecting result as

```
[
   NewStruct(name: "Ankit", slot: ["1","2","3"] ,id: 11),
   NewStruct(name: "Deric", slot:["1","2"], id: 12),
   NewStruct (name: "RandomName1", slot: ["1"], id: 13),
   NewStruct(name: "RandomName2", slot: ["1"], id: 14)
]
```

I need help please can someone help me out, am new to swift programming.
I want to use this data to populate it in a collection view which is inside a Table view, where tableview shows me the name and collection view inside that table view shows me the all the slots for particular name, I did it in the react native i.e javascript code, using reduce method, not able to get it here though....

Comment: You need either to use dictionary of name or create another struct wich contains an array of slot.

Comment: `var slot:String`: Why is it a `String`? Could it be a `[String]` instead? You could either change your `MyStruct` model, and in the `init(from decoder:)` handle that case to have a `var slots: [String]`, OR use a different struct designed specifically for your `UITableView`: `MyStructViewModel`, that can be populated from various `MyStructModel`. Ie, decoupling code into multiple layers.

Comment: Can you just help me out to solve this issue, you are rite i should use another struct , can you do it using some another struct?? Plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce(into:)` to merge into a dictionary and then use the values of the dictionary

```
let merged = arrayOfData
    .reduce(into: [:]) {
        $0[$1.id, default: NewStruct(name: $1.name, slot: [], id: $1.id)].slot.append($1.slot)
    }
    .values
```